# WPF UserControls display left when I specify HorizontalAlignment="Right"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my WPF UserControl code reduced to the relevant part:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AKPS.View.UserCalibWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           >


        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Width="1600" >
        <Button   Height="45" Width="100" />
        <Button   Height="45" Width="100" />                
    </StackPanel>
```

Why do the 2 buttons display on the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StackPanel` does exactly that - it stacks elements together, in your case, horizontally. Your `HorizontalAlignment` is referring to the stack panel, which will shift it to the right, not the buttons inside them.

Instead, perhaps try using a `Grid` instead of a `StackPanel`, and then placing your `StackPanel` (with no `Width` element set) inside it.

Comment: I did that for an easy fix. Thx a ton :)

Answer (score 3):

You are having a `Width` for your `StackPanel` removing that will align your stack panel to right with your controls in it.

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  >
    <Button Height="45" Width="100" />
    <Button Height="45" Width="100" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

`HorizontalAlignment` controls the container's alignment.

Try `HorizontalContentAlignment` instead.

---

As Abin indicated, in my haste I'd forgotten StackPanel doesn't have a HorizontalContentAlignment property.

You could achieve similar functionality with a DockPanel though, or use Abin's solution.

Comment: there is no property on `StackPanel` called `HorizontalContentAlignment` but as you said SO was setting the container alignment.

Comment: @AbinMathew oops, indeed!